# Инициализировать в пользовательском классе объекты из стандартной библиотеки

Tags: excel, vba

Есть пользовательский класс в котором есть поле содержащее ссылку на лист:

```
Private ws As Worksheet
```

Пишу к нему методы:

```
Property Get TargetWorksheet() As Worksheet
    TargetWorksheet = ws
End Property
Property Set TargetWorksheet(ByRef newws As Worksheet)
    ws = newws
End Property
```

Но при попытке присвоить ссылку этому полю всегда ругается что "object variable or with block variable not set".
Как в таком случае нужно "инициализировать" объекты? (далее будет добавлено поле с объектом Range)

Comment: `set TargetWorksheet = ws` и `set ws = newws`

Answer (score 0):

Все присвоения в отношении объектов в VBA должны быть сделаны через `Set`.

```
Property Get TargetWorksheet() As Worksheet
    set TargetWorksheet = ws
End Property
Property Set TargetWorksheet(ByRef newws As Worksheet)
    set ws = newws
End Property
```